# In DevOpsServer 2019, rules with doubles seem to be different in different locations

Tags: tfs, default, regional-settings, azure-devops-server-2019

In DevOps Server, I am trying to set a default value for the WIT "bug". Story points should always be set to 0.5

So I changed and uploaded the witd in that way:

```
<FIELD name="Story Points" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>The size of work estimated for fixing the bug</HELPTEXT>
    <DEFAULT from="value" value="0.5" />
  </FIELD>
```

I can import and use it in my browser without problems. But each time, a colleague creates a bug and uses german language profile, the value is set to 5 instead of 0.5
Can I change anything in the XML that everyone puts in 0.5?

Comment: That sounds like really wired. Did he just have the different configuration of control in profile of browser? What if  your colleague change the germany language to English profile? Do the value from 5 change to 0.5? And what if he create a new bug in English profile, do he also get a 5 default value of  story point?

Comment: In English profile, it really has the 0.5. But we do not want to force everyone to use the English profile.
The value stays with 5 as the Default value is only used when there is no entry.
It behaves just as if you manually put in 0.5, and in the german profile, the .5 is not supported, but only ,5.

Comment: At the Moment I only see the possibility to force everyone to use the English profile. I just changed it at on colleague and now for him everything works. As it seems that noone else has this problem, I cannot find any "real" answer. It just seems to be a bug, so we have to wait till Microsoft solves it (if they do so). So thanks for your help and thoughts about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems to be a bug on Microsoft side.
And the only way to have the Right values seems to be changing to English profile.
For us, browser and Windows are in German. But we will force colleagues to switch to English profile in DevOps Server.

Answer (score 0):

First to say, sorry we could not reproduce your issue in our side. If manually type 0.5 in german Country/Region profile. It display correctly. Not sure if this related to system and bowser language setting. We are also using English in both computer system and bowser.

[image]

Besides, it's not able to change anything in the XML to bypass local profile setting.

Your input in XML file is correct and this already make sure the default value has `0.5` for Bug WIT.

However according to your description, even with german profile, it's using different format than English or some other language.  The display format should be `.5` which not support, use `,5` instead.  This does mean the value is 5, actually is still 0.5.

If you do not want to make some confusions, better way is using English profile in your situation.